# Extracting Data from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to code a very simple blackjack game and I am currently stuck at a point where I am trying to determine a "winner".

I have an `ArrayList` which represents a deck of cards (`deckOfCards`) and I have an `ArrayList` that represents the cards dealt to n players (`playersCards`).

The idea of the `ArrayList`, `playersCards`, is that up to every 6th spot of the list represents a a different player's hand. For example, if only 2 players were playing it would look like this.

`playersCards[1,2,6,8,6,10,4,6,5,6,3,9]`

And that list would split into, player1's hand `[1,2,6,8,6,10]` and player2's hand `[4,6,5,6,3,9]`.

I am having trouble splitting the playersCards arrayList into n different lists like so.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This block of text is very hard to read. Use blank lines to separate the text into short paragraphs. Use back-ticks to surround code - such as `ArrayList`. Why not use a `List<List<Card>>` in the first place? This is not how cards are dealt in 21 and it does not make sense to represent them in this way.

Comment: What delineates the point between hands?  For example, if there are 2 players and 3 cards have been dealt how do you break the list? Instead of a single ArrayList could you instead use a list of lists, with one inner list per player?  Like so: `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`

Comment: Why on Earth do you not simply have a list for each player? Create a `Player` class that has a `hand` field which is a list of that player's cards. Object Orientation: You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of ways to do this. One of them is with `sublist()`:

```
List<Integer> hand1 = playersCards.subList(0, 6);
List<Integer> hand2 = playersCards.subList(6, 11);
```

Be aware that this gives a view of the `ArrayList`. This means that any changes to the `ArrayList` will be reflected in the view.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, sublist 1 would have indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and sublist 2 would have indices 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  That looks correct to me.  It's more helpful to point out the mistake rather than assert a mistake has been made.

Comment: There are 6 cards for each, not 5

Comment: What @JaqenH'ghar said.